# sql pivot and calculated column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to put together a query that shows me month by month revenue by customer as well as a SUM(Revenue) of all the months in the last column. So far I have this query below. This is as close as I could get to what I am looking for:

```
SELECT cust_num as Customer, CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 120) AS 'Month',
       SUM(q1.amount) AS Revenue
FROM
  (SELECT cust_num, inv_date AS date,
          SUM(amount) AS amount
   FROM artran_mst
   WHERE (type = 'i') and cust_num = 'HON0994' and (inv_date BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '2/23/2017')
   GROUP BY cust_num, inv_date

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT cust_num, inv_date AS date,
       SUM(amount*-1) AS amount
   FROM artran_mst
   WHERE (TYPE = 'c') and cust_num = 'HON0994' AND (inv_date BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '2/23/2017')
   GROUP BY cust_num, inv_date

   UNION ALL 
   SELECT cust_num, inv_date AS date,
                    SUM(amount) AS amount
   FROM artran_mst
   WHERE (TYPE = 'd') and cust_num = 'HON0994'
     AND (inv_date BETWEEN '1/1/2017' AND '2/23/2017')
   GROUP BY cust_num, inv_date) q1
GROUP BY cust_num, MONTH(date),
         CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), Date, 120)
ORDER BY RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 120),4),
         MONTH(date)
```

It returns the following:

```
+----------+----------+---------+
| Customer |  Month   | Revenue |
+----------+----------+---------+
| HON0994  | Jan 2017 | 1170662 |
| HON0994  | Feb 2017 |  787066 |
+----------+----------+---------+
```

I need to somehow add a pivot and a calculated column to show the months as columns with the last column being a 'total'. See:

```
+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| Customer | Jan 2017 | Feb 2017 |  Total  |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| HON0994  |  1170662 |   787066 | 1957728 |
+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT cust_num,
       (CASE WHEN inv_date >= '2017-01-01' and inv_date < '2017-02-01'
             THEN (case when type = 'c' then - amount else amount end)
        END) as jan_2017,
       (CASE WHEN inv_date >= '2017-02-01' and inv_date < '2017-03-01'
             THEN (case when type = 'c' then - amount else amount end)
        END) as feb_2017,
       SUM(case when type = 'c' then - amount else amount end) as total
FROM artran_mst
WHERE (type = 'i') and cust_num = 'HON0994' and
      (inv_date >= '2017-01-01' and inv_date < '2017-03-01')
GROUP BY cust_num;
```